# How can I sort my List in C# to the Month?

Tags: c#, list, datetime, datetime-format

so I got in C# a String list with a lot of different dates. Now what I want to do is to sort all of these dates to Month. That means, I want for every Month who is represented tho create a single String in this date Format: YYYY0MM.

So that when I got these dates:

**01.02.2003**

**05.02.2003**

**15.02.2004**

**24.03.2003**

That these Dates in this strings Convertet:

**String 1 Value: 2003002**

**String 2 Value: 2004002**

**String 3 Value: 2003003**

Comment: Okay, so that sounds like you want to parse each entry in the original list as a `DateTime`, and reformat it... those are two separate operations - have you managed either of them yet? Please be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: I just got an String list with all dates

Comment: Okay, so do you know how to parse the string into a `DateTime`? Is the problem working with a list rather than an individual `DateTime`? Is it converting the `DateTime` into the new format? The more specific you can be about which part of the broad task you're stuck on, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: the problem is not to parse the string list into an DateTime. The Problem is to sort the list to Month and to change the format to: yyyy0mm

Comment: for every Month I want only one month string

Comment: string[] input = { "01.02.2003", "05.02.2003", "15.02.2004", "24.03.2003" };
            string[] output = input.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => x.ToString("yyyy0MM"))
                .ToArray();

Comment: Right, so if you knew how to format a `DateTime` with a format of `yyyy0mm`, there'd be no other problems? If that's the case, it would be worth editing the question to *just* that part - the rest is irrelevant. (Ah, there's also the distinctness aspect... that could be another question, potentially.)

Comment: The only real problem is to make for every month one string, so that there is no double month or something for every month only 1 String

Comment: So your entire question is really "given a list of strings, how can I make sure no string occurs more than once"? Again, if that's the only part you didn't know, it would be useful to restrict your question to that. Hint: LINQ is great - just use `Distinct()`.

Comment: I tried this now: string[] output = periode.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.ToString(" yyyy0MM")).ToArray();

                            var noDupes = output.Distinct().ToList();  but there are still duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is to convert the dates to 1st of each month and then do distinct to remove the duplicates and order by months:

```
string[] input = { "01.02.2003", "05.02.2003", "15.02.2004", "24.03.2003" };

string[] output = input
.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //parse the strings to dates
.Select(x => x.AddDays(1 - x.Day)) //get first day of each month
.Distinct() //remove the duplicates
.OrderBy(x => x.Month) //order by month
.Select(x => x.ToString("yyyy0MM")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
            var dates = new List<string>() { "01.02.2003", "05.02.2003", "15.02.2004", "24.03.2003"};
            var result = new List<string>();
            dates.ForEach(dateItem =>
            {
            DateTime dateValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateItem, out dateValue))
            {
                result.Add($"{ dateValue.Year}0{dateValue.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')}");
                }
            });
```

After running this code segment "result" variables value will be: {"2003002","2003002","2004002","2003003"}

Comment: This doesn't deal with the uniqueness aspect - the whole thing is more easily done in a single LINQ query, IMO.